# How to append in a pandas dataframe a sequence of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I generated a list of strings as follows:

In:

```
for x in links:    
    full_content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('apath')    
    full_content = [x.text for x in full_content]
    print(full_content)
```

Out: (a very large sequence of lists)

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.']
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip']
...
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.']
```

I tried to append them with:

```
full_content = pd.DataFrame([x.text for x in full_content])
```

However, instead of generating a single dataframe it is actually generating one. How can I append the aforementioned sequence of lists into a single pandas dataframe without the quotes (`' '`)?:

```
     col1
0    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
1    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
...
3   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(x.text) for x in full_content]` instead?

Comment: I all ready tried it. However I got: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'` @kiran.koduru

Comment: What do you get when you paste `dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(x) for x in full_content]` __after__ `full_content = [x.text for x in full_content]`

Comment: @kiran.koduru `PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Comment: `a = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]; pd.DataFrame(a)` works. Can you elaborate (hopefully with examples) on what is `full_content` that is printed and what kind of dataframe are you expecting to get?

Comment: Sure @DennisGolomazov, I edited the question with more details. Note that I do not have a nested list. I am only printing each list with the for loop.

Comment: Ok, this also works `a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; pd.DataFrame(a)`. I also don't understand this phrase `However, instead of generating a single dataframe it is actually generating one.` Can you give more details?

Comment: @DennisGolomazov, sure I am getting a dataframe with size 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So think I understand this is what you are trying to do. You want to create a pandas dataframe for each `full_content` and then append it to a list of `frames`. Finally you can merge all dataframes with `pd.concat`.
    import pandas as pd

```
frames = []
counter_from = 0
for x in links:    
    driver.get(x)
    full_content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="segment"]')    
    full_content = [x.text for x in full_content]
    len_items = len(full_content)
    counter_to = counter_from + len_items


    data = {'text' : pd.Series(full_content, 
                               index=[i for i in range(counter_from, counter_to))])}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    frames.append(df)
    counter_from += len_items

result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!. However it is actually appending one element. When I do: `result.size` I get: 1, instead of a dataframe with more rows.

Comment: @tumbleweed I just updated my answer. Please check again.

Comment: @tumbleweed if my answer works for you. Please accept it.

Comment: Thanks kiran!. I got this: `NameError: name 'text' is not defined` in line: `len_items = len(text)`

Comment: @tumbleweed Oops. Those were names for my test data. Updated my answer again.

Comment: Now when I do `results.size`: `0`

Comment: @tumbleweed and you get the output for `full_content` as the one mentioned above in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127326/discussion-between-kiran-koduru-and-tumbleweed).

Comment: Yes, any idea of another approach to try?.